# Pass std::iterator pointing to a vector of Eigen types

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a large `std::vector<Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>>` sitting somewhere in memory. I can pass iterators to this vector to a function, like below:

```
typedef std::vector<Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dyanamic, 1>>::iterator ArrayIterator;

void MyFunction(ArrayIterator v1_beg, ArrayIterator v1_end,
                ArrayIterator v2_beg, ArrayIterator v2_end) {

   Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> tmp(*v1_beg.size());
   tmp.setZero(); 
   while (v1_beg != v1_end) { tmp += *v1_beg++ * *v2_beg++; }

}
```

I know that passing `Eigen` types to functions can be a tricky business if one wants to avoid temporaries. The above solution seems to avoid temporaries (e.g. printing `&(*v_beg).data()` gives the correct memory address of the location in the external vector). However, due to the subtleties involved in passing pure `Eigen` types, it almost seems "too easy". My question is: can I be confident that an approach like above will not result in the creation of temporaries? Or might the temporary be invoked when I dereference (`*v1_beg`)?

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `*v1_beg` will return a reference to a `Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>` (which is the same as `Eigen::ArrayXf`, btw), no Eigen code is invoked up to that place. The actual Eigen code then calls (semi pseudo code):

```
ArrayXf::operator+=(operator*(const ArrayXf&, const ArrayXf&))
```

which indeed works without temporaries.